# Server in web which allow test socket gathering info

Tags: java, sockets, time

my question is quite hard to formulate.
Well, is there any server in whole web which one would be able work with testing sockets?
For example to send to server "somehow" and get hmm.. time in the world, or any fancy info.

Please correct english if i make mistake and topic if it makes missunderstood.

Comment: You could code up your own Socket-based server or grab some similar code from the web from any Sockets tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own or use http://code.google.com/p/softenido/wiki/echoserver.  I think you can install simple tcp services in windows which will allow you to connect to echo on port 7.  Of course you can always use open web servers:

```
c:\> telnet www.google.com 80
```

Then type "GET /" and hit enter twice.  You should get google's web page.